# What is texmf folder in my home directory? (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu

In my home directory (ubuntu), there is a folder named texmf. I guess it has something to do with my latex installation but it has only 12.5 kB. What is this folder for? Can I safely delete it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The directory is *very* important, don't remove it. When LaTeX needs to create some file (typically font related) it will store them there.

Comment: Its also a folder where you can easily install your own packages or packages which are not part of your tex distribution or where you need a newer version then the one in your tex distribution.